# Setting up WSO2 with a valid certificate of my company

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

how can setting up ESB with a valid certificate? i created a new jks and signed with calid certificate like [here](https://www.yenlo.com/blog/setting-up-wso2-with-a-valid-certificate) . i had pfx file so firstly Created a new keystore, after that exported a public key from my JKS file next to add the keystore and public key to the Wso2 Esb and add the public key to the Public truststore. i Configured the product to use the new keystore but when restart Esb i don't see any service published on 8243 port like this : https://esb.test.com:8243/services/test?wsdl

Comment: What do you mean by you don't see?

Comment: i mean certificate is not valid for 9443 port and can't access to any service on 8243 port.

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: not error just not valid certificate , do you have any step by step solution for set up a valid certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this document on how to create and configure 
 a new certificate. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Creating+New+Keystores